# In Circuit What is R ,Y ,B written in box?

Tags: power-electronics

sir,
I will make a automatic single phase changer. and I found a circuit on a net.
I have a doubt related to circuit.

1 ) according to this circuit we need a step down a phase.

2)  what is a R,Y,B in box.

[image]

Comment: Dear Mitesh, not all here are "sirs"; there's some ladies on here, too. Anyway, no need to be so formal. A question doesn't benefit by an "honorary" salutation.

Comment: at a relay also mark R,Y,B.

Answer (score 1):

In the country where this circuit was published, you will almost certainly find the colour code for 3-phase wiring uses Red, Yellow and Blue wires for the three phases.

Searching "Three phase color codes" leads to [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase_electric_power#Color_codes) which shows Red, Yellow and Blue were used in the UK (before 2006), Europe (before 2004) and India, so you are either looking at a fairly old European circuit or an Indian one.

Answer (score 0):

R,Y,B are just letters given to identify the phases.  You need a three phase to one phase transformer to go with this.  Apparently they are telling you to use a step down transformer.  I don't know what DC level you are starting with.  The DC would be connected to one end of the three input phases.  Make sure to pay attention to the dots on the phases.  The other end of each phase goes to the common of one of the R,Y,B relays.  The voltage at the common of each of these relays is taken back to the input opto-isolator to determine when each phase should be on.  The single phase AC will appear at the output of the transformer.  I'm not sure how they are regulating the voltage or frequency from my quick look.

Comment: what about a R,Y,B at a relay.

Comment: The ones at the relay connect right back to the opto-isolators from the switched end of the transformer.  They also connect to the opposite end of the phase windings from the DC input.